# case compare to number and give out name

Tags: sql, database, select, case

the problem I have is that I have a column called cate with the numbers 1 to 5 but I want alias names in the print out.
For example if the column has the number 1 I want STONE in the result set, if it is 2 I want "TREE".

I should look something like

```
    Select
    case when t.cate = 1 then t.cate="STONE"
    case when t.cate = 2 then t.cate="TREE"
    else null end as test from dbt.tbl t
```

I do not want to change the value in the table only in the print out.

Any idea how I can that to work?

Thanks for all your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove extra case,

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN t.cate = 1 THEN 'STONE'
             WHEN t.cate = 2 THEN 'TREE'
             ELSE null 
         END AS test 
FROM    dbt.tbl t
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can write

```
SELECT
  CASE t.cate
    WHEN 1 THEN 'STONE'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'TREE'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS test
FROM dbt.tbl t
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is likely to change in the future (either through edits or additions), I'd do it as a separate table:

```
INSERT INTO Cates (Cate,Description) VALUES
(1,'Stone'),
(2,'Tree') --Etc
```

And then just do:

```
SELECT c.Description as Test
FROM dbt.tbl t inner join Cates c on t.Cate = c.Cate
```

Comment: I can't alter or add tables.